# How to get arrays from another php class

Tags: php, arrays, yii, yii1.x

I have following code in my class called `lang.php`:

```
<?php $GLOBALS['app_list_strings']['country']=array (
.....
)


    ...
?>
```

These array is not defined inside any function and class.
I need to get these array values in other controller class. (For example, `AdminController.php`). How can I access these array values?(`$GLOBALS['app_list_strings']['country']`)

Comment: Got an example of a class you want to get this into?

Comment: Are you using any framework ?

Comment: I am using yii 1 framework

Comment: I highly recommend not using globals just for best practices. If you want, I could write you an answer in normal PHP. I am not sure if yii is any different from the base in the case that I can give. Would you like that?

Comment: I will  be very greatfull, if you help me

Answer (score 1):

You can just inject your other class into your `AdminController` class and set up a `get` method to fetch the array(s) you need. Presumably you have your class set up like so *(obviously there would be more script)*:

```
class Lang
    {
        public function someMethod()
            {
                $array =  array(
                    'app_list_strings'=>array(
                        'country'=>array(
                            'k1'=>'val1',
                            'k2'=>'v2'
                        )
                    )
                );
            }
    }
```

If you add a private parameter and a method you can extract that array:

```
class Lang
    {
        # Create parameter
        private $array;
        # Whatever method contains the array
        public function someMethod()
            {
                # use $this here
                $this->array = array(
                    'app_list_strings'=>array(
                        'country'=>array(
                            'k1'=>'val1',
                            'k2'=>'v2'
                        )
                    )
                );
                # I am just returning self for sake of demonstration.
                return $this;
            }
        # Returns the array
        public function getArray()
            {
                return $this->array;
            }
    }

class AdminController
    {
        # Inject your other class
        public function whateverMethod(Lang $lang)
            {
                # Retrieve array from getArray() method
                print_r($lang->someMethod()->getArray());
            }
    }
```

To use:

```
<?php
$AdminController = new AdminController();
$AdminController-> whateverMethod(new Lang());
```

To get the array just in general:

```
<?php
$Lang = new Lang();
print_r($Lang->someMethod()->getArray());
```

If the classes are far removed from each other, in that they are called from different areas of your script and they can not be injected like demonstrated, you can change `private $array` to `private static $array` and assign `self::$array = array(...etc.` then return `self::$array`. Because it's static it will persist through the script. Last way would be to save to `$_SESSION`, but that may not be the most desirable solution.